# IE7/8 javascript "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've got a site under development which uses Google Maps API V3 to load multiple location makers. Everything is working except in IE7/8 where my looping through an array fails due to the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '5': object is null or undefined
```

I've looked through all similar questions on StackOverflow and can't find any solution.

So I'm trying to access data from an object array (I also tried a nested array but the same error occurs). My array is as below. I have also tried dropping the html object in case that was causing an issue, but no change - IE7/8 still can't get the object value.

```
var sites = [
    {title: "Hermitage Medical Clinic", latitude: 53.3593139774, longitude: -6.40494071541, enumerator: 1, html: "<div class=\"find_a_surgeon_info_inner\"><h4 style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\">Hermitage Medical Clinic</h4><p>Old Lucan Road, Dublin 20</p><p><a href=\"http://devel.pixelapes.com/iaps.ie/location/hermitage-medical-clinic/\">View hospital details</a></p></div>", iconTerm: "hospital" }
        ];
```

And here's my function which is trying to access the data:

```
        function setMarkers(map, sites) {

            for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
                // var sites = markers[i];
                var icon = '<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/map-icons/' + sites[i].iconTerm + '.png';
                var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[i].latitude, sites[i].longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: siteLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    title: sites[i].title,
                    zIndex: sites[i].enumerator,
                    html: sites[i].html
                });

                var contentString = "Some content";

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        }
```

I've also tried dropping back to just using the default Maps marker in case there was a specific issue with the iconTerm object but IE7/8 just fails trying to get the next object value.

Here's a page on which this is occurring:
http://devel.pixelapes.com/iaps.ie/surgeon/eamon-s-beausang/

Strangely, I have another map instance where I'm not setting the bounds with map.fitBounds. The failure to get object values still occurs but the map sort of loads (but very messily): http://devel.pixelapes.com/iaps.ie/find-a-hospital-or-clinic/

I have tried removing the fitBounds functionality on the single surgeon page but the map still doesn't partially load as it does on the "Find a hospital" map.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There  are trailing comma's after the last items of `sites` and `latlngs`, remove them, IE doesn't like trailing commas in arrays/objects.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle! I totally didn't spot that and it was driving me mad! Only reason the trailing comma is there is because I'm generating the object from a PHP loop and forgot to count the array and drop the trailing comma on the last object.

Comment: Sadly it hasn't completely solved my IE7/8 woes as I'm still having trouble getting the markers to show up - but this is definitely step one of my issues fixed!

Should I post a new question about the markers not showing?

Comment: Heh, I've just worked out the issue with the markers disappearing... a generic CSS img rule was affecting them with margins and padding... I'm an idiot (but then IE's dev tools don't let you actually look inside the map so I couldn't see what was going on)

Comment: @Dr.Molle  what are you talking about? I don't see any trailing commas. In addition, IE DEMANDS trailing commas in JSON objects, so your answer seems so strange to me.

Comment: Your comment is much stranger, 1. we are talking about IE7+IE8 , 2: there are two linked pages(and you may assume that they didn't respond with a server-error 10 month ago but did contain the code with trailing commas)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that IE does not like one (or more) of the property names you have chosen for the members of the `sites` Array. I suggest changing your first code section to this:

```
var sites = [{
        "title": "Hermitage Medical Clinic",
        "latitude": 53.3593139774,
        "longitude": -6.40494071541,
        "enumerator": 1,
        "html": "<div class=\"find_a_surgeon_info_inner\"><h4 style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\">Hermitage Medical Clinic</h4><p>Old Lucan Road, Dublin 20</p><p><a href=\"http://devel.pixelapes.com/iaps.ie/location/hermitage-medical-clinic/\">View hospital details</a></p></div>",
        "iconTerm": "hospital"
}];
```

Comment: You were actually correct now that I look back at your code but Dr. Molle's answer defined the actual flaw. It was just the trailing comma that was causing the issue but having the property names in quotation marks didn't make any difference.